# How to prove $\limsup\limits{} \left(A_n \cap B_n\right)\subseteq\limsup\limits{} \left(A_n \right) \cap \limsup\limits{}\left(B_n \right) $?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Prove that for any collections $\{A_n\}$  and $\{B_n\}$, 
$$\limsup\limits{} \left(A_n \cap B_n\right)\subseteq\limsup\limits{} \left(A_n \right) \cap \limsup\limits{}\left(B_n \right) $$

Any hints please? Right now, i have following relation as the beginning:

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(A_k \cap B_k\right) \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(A_k \right) \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(B_k \right)$$

I can see it intuitively. Should i start it by using substitution?

Comment: Start at the beginning. What is the limsup of a sequence of sets?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\lim \sup A_n$ is the set of elements that belong to an infinite number of $A_n$,s. So if

$$\omega \in \lim \sup \ (A_k \cap B_k),$$

we know that $\omega$ belongs to $(A_k \cap B_k)$ for an infinite number of $k$'s. We conclude that $\omega$ belongs to an infinite number of $A_k$'s AND belongs to an infinite number of $B_k's$. Therefore, $\omega \in \lim \sup (A_k) \ \cap \ \lim \sup \ (B_k)$.
$$$$

Comment: Well, thank you firstly. What you said is what i meant for "i can see it intuitively", i think there is a gap between the 2nd sentence and 3rd sentence which starts with 'we conclude that...'. Or this is enough for prove this problem?

Comment: There is no gap. Suppose that $\omega \in A_k \cap B_k$. Then $\omega \in A_k$ and $\omega \in B_k$. Since this occurs for infinite $k$'s, we conclude that...

Comment: I see. The crucial part is infinite k's. Thank you.